# RODBC Cannot allocate memory

Tags: r, unixodbc, rodbc

Simple R script

```
library(RODBC)
odbChannel <- odbcConnect(dsn = "CTPRD03", uid = "BD_RPT_RO", pwd = "****")
df.test <- sqlQuery(channel = odbChannel, query = "select * from DUAL;")
df.test
close(odbChannel)
```

Produces the following error

> shiny@narc07shiny1dev:~/software> Rscript ./RODBC_SIMPLE_TEST.r
>   
> Error in odbcQuery(channel, query, rows_at_time) : 
>  
>   **'Calloc' could not allocate memory (18446744073709551616 of 22816
>   bytes)** 
> Calls: sqlQuery -> odbcQuery -> .Call 
> Execution
>   halted 
> Warning message: 
> closing unused RODBC handle 1

Tested odbc outside of R and was able to get results. I'm not sure where the problem is at this point. I'm thinking it is RODBC.

Already uninstalled RODBC and reinstalled the RODBC package and there were no errors during that process, but still have the same results.

Found one case out there with the same problem but there wasn't any resolution.
What would be next steps in isolating the problem, any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using 32bit or 64bit R?

Comment: It does appear that there might be an issue x86 and x64 ODBC and R 
unixODBC-32bit-2.2.12-198.17

R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) -- "Pumpkin Helmet"
Copyright (C) 2014 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-suse-linux-gnu (64-bit)

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar problem and fixed by adding rows_at_time = 1 to the connection.

```
odbChannel <- odbcConnect(dsn = "CTPRD03", uid = "BD_RPT_RO", pwd = "****", rows_at_time = 1)
```

I also found this blurb in the documentation:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/RODBC.pdf

Several errors which have been reported as bugs in RODBC 1.3-0 which were in fact ODBC driver
errors that can be circumvented by setting rows_at_time = 1 (and the warning under that argument
has always been there). The drivers involved have been third-party Oracle drivers and old SQL
Server drivers.

Comment: Just tried your suggestion and unfortunately it did not resolve the problem.   I get the same error. We have switched to using JDBC and it is working fine for us.

Comment: That is good to know.  In my case it worked for SQL, I didn't try Oracle.

Comment: this worked for me ... using odbcDriverConnect(...,rows_at_time = 1). Though I got a warning which I don't know if it is related: Warning message:
In .Internal(sys.call(which)) : closing unused RODBC handle 2

Answer (score 1):

I kept having this problem for large tables, worked perfectly for smaller tables but not more than 10,000 rows. I was using:
con <- odbcDriverConnect ("driver={SQL Server}; server=SERVERName; database=dBName; uid=Name; pwd=password")

I simply changed the driver from 'SQL Server' to 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' and now I can work with table of any size.

Answer (score -1):

What type of database architecture are you connecting to? If it doesn't match the version of R you're using, the query won't run. For example, if you're using 64-bit R but you are trying to connect to a Microsoft Access 2007 or earlier database (which is 32-bit) you won't be able to run the query.

If you're using R Studio, go to the 'Tools' menu then 'Global Options' and you can change the version of R you're using to match that of the database.

Comment: The target DB is Oracle 11.2.0.4 on Windows x86. In this case we were just testing R locally on a SUSE Enterprise Linux x64 ultimately we will be using Shiny Server Pro. Testing unixODBC using  isql worked fine. I will try using and instance of Oracle running on x64 SUSE to see if I get the same error.

Comment: Did a test using Oracle x64  11.2.0.4 running on an SUSE. Got the same error message