# sqlQuery failing with memory error when row_at_time too large

Tags: sql-server, r, memory, rodbc

I am sending this query to a sql server in R using `RODBC::sqlQuery`

```
MERGE "mytable" AS Target USING ( VALUES ('myname','POLYGON ((148.0000000000000000 -20.0000000000000000, 148.0000000000000000 -20.0000000000000000, 148.0000000000000000 -20.0000000000000000, 148.0000000000000000 -20.0000000000000000, 148.0000000000000000 -20.0000000000000000))')) AS Source ("name","polygon")
                   ON (Target."name" = Source."name")
                   WHEN MATCHED THEN
                   UPDATE SET Target."polygon" = Source."polygon"
                   WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
                   INSERT ("name","polygon")
                   VALUES (Source."name", Source."polygon")
                   OUTPUT $action, Inserted.*, Deleted.*
```

It fails when `row_at_time` argument of `sqlQuery` is more than 10,
`Error in odbcQuery(channel, query, rows_at_time) : 
  'Calloc' could not allocate memory (107374182400 of 1 bytes)`

but works if `row_at_time` < 10. (still the query takes quite a few seconds which is surprising as the table is indexed and very small: less than 100 rows)

Any idea why?
Thank you

EDIT: This is the structure of the table I am writing on:

[image]

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sql server 12.0.4100.1

Comment: Does the same query run directly on SQL Server?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It works in R if I specify row_at_time=1 (but it is slow).
The same query works in toad and seems quite fast.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30581046/rodbc-cannot-allocate-memory) might be of help.